# How to resolve the issue - Yii framework

Tags: php, mysqli, yii2, cpanel, whm

I am getting the following below error when running the query using the yii framework. I am not find myself to resolve this issue can you please help to recover and resolve it where I am doing wrong in to that.

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), 2) + POW(69.1 * (- items.longitude) * COS(items.latitude / 57.3), 2)),2) as d' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT items.*,round(SQRT( POW(69.1 * (items.latitude - ), 2) + POW(69.1 * (- items.longitude) * COS(items.latitude / 57.3), 2)),2) as distance,u.id as userId,u.first_name,u.last_name
>   FROM `10yoyo_shared_item` `items`
>   JOIN `10yoyo_user` `u` ON items.user_id=u.id
>   WHERE items.home_page_display_status="Y" AND items.status="active" AND items.category_id = "62" AND u.status="active" HAVING distance <=10000
>   ORDER BY `shared_time` DESC LIMIT 4

The statement executed was:

```
SELECT items.*,round(SQRT( POW(69.1 * (items.latitude - ), 2) + POW(69.1 * (- items.longitude) * COS(items.latitude / 57.3), 2)),2) as distance,u.id as userId,u.first_name,u.last_name
FROM `10yoyo_shared_item` `items`
JOIN `10yoyo_user` `u` ON items.user_id=u.id
WHERE items.home_page_display_status="Y" AND items.status="active" AND items.category_id = "62" AND u.status="active" HAVING distance <=10000
ORDER BY `shared_time` DESC LIMIT 4
```

Thanks,
Sorabh

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: The code is there? It's badly formatted, but it's there.

Comment: This is just exception, not code which throwed it.

Comment: The `,2` of your query is out of scope of the first `SQRT` function. Voted to close due to typo. Try to format this query and the error will pop up quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i resolved my error by replacing the sqrt function with the following codes as below:

```
      DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(items.latitude))
     * COS(RADIANS("'.$latitude.'"))
     * COS(RADIANS(items.longitude - "'.$longitude.'"))
     + SIN(RADIANS(items.latitude))
     * SIN(RADIANS("'.$latitude.'")))) AS distance
```

Thanks and Regards,
Sorabh